# save embedding layer in pytorch model

Tags: pytorch

i have this model:

```py
class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3,stride= 1,padding=1)
      # self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3,stride= 1,padding=1)
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(24576, 128)
      self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
      self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout2d(0.5)
      self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)
      self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
      x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
      # x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
      x = F.max_pool2d(x, (2,2))
      # print(x.shape)
      x = x.view(-1,24576)
      x = self.bn(F.relu(self.fc1(x)))
      x = self.dropout1(x)
      embeding_stage = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
      x = self.fc3(embeding_stage)

      return x
```

and i want to save the embeding_stage layer like i save the model here:

```
model = model()
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'C:\project\count_speakers\model_pytorch.h5')
```

thanks,
Ayal

Comment: what do you mean by saving `embeding_stage` ? do you want to save `self.fc2()` layer?

Comment: why does `torch.save` not meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "save the embedding_stage layer" but if you want to save fc2 or fc3 or something, then you can do that with torch.save().
Ex: to save fc3: `torch.save(model.fc3),'C:\...\fc3.pt')`

### Edit:

Op wants to have the output of the embedding_stage.
You can do that in several ways:

- load your model with `model.load_state_dict(torch.load('C:\...\model_pytorch.h5'))`
  then `model = nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[:-1])`. The output of model is the embeding_stage.
- make a `Model2(nn.Module)`, exactly the same as your first `Model()`, but replace `return x` in `def forward(self, x):` with `return embeding_stage`. Then load the state of your first model into your second model like this: `model2.load_state_dict(torch.load('C:\...\model_pytorch.h5'))`
  Like this fc3 will be loaded, but not used. The output of model2(x) will be the embeding_stage.

Comment: What I meant was that after saving I want to load the model again and then test the model but not get the results of the full model but one step earlier, ie: val_outputs = model(val_inputs)  but val_output is in size 10 like fc2